# SQL Partition By Date and Sequence

Tags: oracle

Below is my data.

| Date | Item | Location | Seqn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/25/2022 17:00 | A1234 | L1 | 2 |
| 3/4/2022 18:00 | A1234 | L1 | 1 |
| 4/7/2022 3:00 | A1234 | L1 | 2 |
| 4/7/2022 3:00 | A1234 | L1 | 4 |
| 4/7/2022 3:00 | A1234 | L1 | 6 |
| 4/8/2022 11:00 | A1234 | L1 | 1 |
| 4/13/2022 8:00 | A1234 | L1 | 2 |
| 4/16/2022 17:00 | A1234 | L1 | 2 |
| 4/29/2022 15:00 | A1234 | L1 | 1 |
| 5/10/2022 5:00 | A1234 | L1 | 2 |
| 5/10/2022 5:00 | A1234 | L1 | 4 |
| 5/10/2022 5:00 | A1234 | L1 | 6 |
| 5/10/2022 5:00 | A1234 | L1 | 8 |
| 5/10/2022 5:00 | A1234 | L1 | 10 |
| 5/19/2022 4:00 | A1234 | L1 | 1 |

I need to separate using partition by and row_number based on date and sequence. As i would like to get the first record of each date.
Below table would be the result of the above example:

| Date | Item | Location | Seqn | Row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/25/2022 17:00 | A1234 | L1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3/4/2022 18:00 | A1234 | L1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4/7/2022 3:00 | A1234 | L1 | 2 | 1 |
| 4/7/2022 3:00 | A1234 | L1 | 4 | 2 |
| 4/7/2022 3:00 | A1234 | L1 | 6 | 3 |
| 4/8/2022 11:00 | A1234 | L1 | 1 | 1 |

Here is my query:

```
select * from (
WITH test AS (
SELECT 
    row_number() OVER(
        PARTITION BY  Item, Location, Date, Seqn
        ORDER by date, Seqn
    ) row_num,
    date,
    item,
    location,
    seqn
FROM 
    table1
)
SELECT * FROM test WHERE row_num = 1
)T1
where
item='A1234'
and location='L1'
Order by 
trdt,
seqn
```

I have been figure out this for 2 days. Please help

Comment: Please add explanations for why each row in your sample data should or should not appear in your results. As it stands I don't understand the logic you're truing to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ***think*** that what you're missing is that the `date` column includes a time component, and you need to remove that before using it in the `PARTITION BY`.

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT 
    row_number() OVER (
      PARTITION BY item, location, seqn, TRUNC(date)
          ORDER BY date
    )
      AS row_num,
    date,
    item,
    location,
    seqn
  FROM 
    table1
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
      row_num  = 1
  AND item     = 'A1234'
  AND location = 'L1'
ORDER BY 
  location,
  item,
  seqn,
  date
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working now.

`WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT 
    row_number() OVER (
      PARTITION BY item, location, TRUNC(date)
          ORDER BY date, seqn
    )
      AS row_num,
    item,
    location,
    seqn
  FROM 
    table1
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sorted
WHERE row_num  = 1`